# Android opening the directions app set on the phone

Tags: android

Currently in my app I am opening Google maps with directions via the following code:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = 
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+site_details.getMap_coordinates());
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Where `site_details.getMap_coordinates()` contains the map coordinates. The above works well with Google maps but will not work with other map apps for example:

- Waze
- HERE WeGo
- etc.

Is there a way I can open other apps with the navigation directions irrespective of the installed app? That is, I want to open the app set on the phone as the direction app with the coordinates without the need to specify it is Google maps.

Comment: I'm not sure it would help but I wanted to share.
Yandex Sample ;
Uri uri = Uri.parse("yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?ll=37.62,55.75&z=12");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: You can only hardcode queries for each app and checking if it's installed, because there is no default intent for navigation

Answer (score 0):

From the [google documentation page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Maps) about intents you can see that you can use the [geo scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme) for making a general intent for opening a location in an app that supports that scheme.

This will not start navigation automatically though.

From [that page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Maps) combined with [this maps documentation page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation), it seems there is no such thing in general, because on [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) they seem to imply that for turn by turn navigation, there is no general scheme to use.

This means that for turn by turn navigation, every app has their own custom intent filter.